# Why do Hollywood movies add small scenes with Indian or Chinese actors and products?

Tags: casting, american-cinema

I have noticed a trend in Hollywood movies where they tend to add small scenes that include Indian or Bollywood actors, or scenes set in China or with famous Chinese actors and products.

My assumption is that they do this to increase sales of movies in the Indian and Chinese market since both have a very large population.  Is there another reason why they would do this?  Has anyone from the industry vocalized reasons behind doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is opinion based... There are specific examples of studios  recutting films to feature longer scenes with characters from China particularly... one particularly recent example being the third [Iron Man](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2324077/Iron-Man-3-execs-changed-film-Chinese-audience-adding-4-minutes-Chinese-actors.html) film.

Comment: `why do Hollywood movies` <-- makes it unclear.  Possible to add examples of such scenes in a specific movie(s)?

Comment: No, "why" can easily be answered - to attract viewers. Without sufficient Chinese characters, a film may not be allowed in theaters in China.

Comment: Nothing about this question seems unclear or primarily opinion-based in any way.

Comment: But why not? If you go out in the US on a regular day you will see a lot of Chinese and Indians. So that is ought be presented in films as it is real.

Comment: The satirical series [Honest Trailers had a great parody of how Transformers: Age Of Extinction is an example of this trend](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Zz5vEfa7UvI). China and India are among the world's fastest-growing cinema markets, and many American film-makers, unsure of how to attract these markets through conventional means like good storytelling and universal themes, are being rather clumsy and unsubtle in their attempts to attract Chinese and Indian movie fans. Shoehorning in familiar faces and locations is one example.

Answer (score 0):

**Because that is a regular thing.**

Regular but how? I've not been to the US but it is pretty obvious that many Indians live and work in the US, not just Indians, Chinese as well. That's something that is true, which is a common sight, i.e if you go out on the streets on a regular day in almost any state of the US where most Hollywood movies are shot you will see Indians and Chinese.

I believe there is nothing like a marketing strategy, if yes, then that's a pretty lame one and I believe big movies don't require that, like Deadpool, that one role of an Indian Taxi Driver was not a big deal, it was a small role but managed to get a lot of attention, that's just the magic the movie makers put in the character nothing because of the nationality. The true fact is that many Taxi drivers in the US are Indians so why wouldn't it be great to cast an Indian to do that role?

They're presenting the truth, there are Indians and Chinese in the US, so if they do not present it the same way in their movies that'd be going south of what's the reality.

Though if someone is doing a Hollywood movie that is set in the ancient period (assuming the movie is centered around Romans or the English, etc.), I do not think there would be much Indians or Chinese in that movie.

Comment: OP isn't asking about coincidental Chinese or Indian actors in US movies, but movies that have extra scenes dedicated to Chinese or Indian Markets. And the Deadpool taxi driver being Indian is basically a racist stereotype (even if it's accurate).